# pluginthreadasynccall hangs the browser

Tags: npapi

I need to call a javascript function from my plugin. In order to do that I have spawned a thread using npnfuncs->pluginthreadasynccall(savedinstance, wcfEventForwarder, NULL). Inside wcfEventForwarder thread function, I am waiting for messages (on a POSIX message Q) which are posted by another library. My intention is to receive these messages and then pass the data (received in these messages) to Javascript. 
The issue is, when I am spwaing the thread using  pluginthreadasynccall(...) from Invoke, the browser is hanging and I am not able to interact with the browser any more. Can you please help me with a solution?

Regards,
Souvik

Comment: you have put the same comments on two different answers; you have indicated that you resolved your issue.  I see that you're new(ish) to stackoverflow, make sure you remember to upvote anything that was helpful and mark an answer

Answer (score 1):

You have completely misunderstood the purpose of NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall; it is not to start a new thread, but to run something on the main thread. Your wcfEventForwarder function will be called on the main thread, so if you then block it's going to hang the whole plugin.

the purpose of this function call is to give you a way to trigger a call back on the main thread since other then NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall, no NPN_ functions can be called on other threads. If you want to spawn another thread, you should do it yourself using something like boost::thread or the threading APIs directly (pick your flavor).

You should also note that some of the newer browsers have apparently stopped supporting NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall; in particular, it doesn't seem to work in Safari 5.1 on windows or mac and I've had problems with it on multiple other browsers (firefox and chrome) in certain configurations on Mac.

Comment: OK, I understand your point. Thanks a lot for the clarification. Now, what I have done is that I have created a thread using pthread library and from the thread body, I am calling - npnfuncs->pluginthreadasynccall(savedinstance,wcfEventForwarder,NULL); If I understood it right, this should run in the context of the newly created thread and should not freeze my browser. But even after doing this I notice the same problem. I am using firefox 3.6.22. Am I missing some thing here?

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my previous post. It was stupid of me. Now I am able to get it running. I have moved the waiting to pthread and makes a call to pluginthreadasynccall(...) to send the information back to the browser. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Comment: if I were you, I'd seriously consider using FireBreath (http://www.firebreath.org) for your plugin; it solves pretty much all of this for you as well as handling a lot of tricky edge cases on different platform.s

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall` from another thread , or inside the "plug-in thread"?

Comment: OK, I understand your point. Thanks a lot for the clarification. Now, what I have done is that I have created a thread using pthread library and from the thread body, I am calling -                            npnfuncs->pluginthreadasynccall(savedinstance,wcfEventForwarder,NULL); If I understood it right, this should run in the context of the newly created thread and should not freeze my browser. But even after doing this I notice the same problem. I am using firefox 3.6.22. Am I missing some thing here?

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my previous post. It was stupid of me. Now I am able to get it running. I have moved the waiting to pthread and makes a call to pluginthreadasynccall(...) to send the information back to the browser. Thanks a lot for your suggestions.